# How to get tabs component from JTabbedPane

Tags: swing

I would like to know if it is possible to retrieve the component containing tabs from a JTabbedPane, so that I could put it in a BorderLayout north position and the tab pane would be in the BorderLayout center position ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any point in doing that - by default tabs are in north position.

And also - no, you cannot do that anyway - you cannot separate tabs from tab content area since it is a single component combined by TabbedPaneUI. You can specify tabs position relative to content though using `setTabPlacement` method. For example you can change it to EAST placement:

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane ();
tabbedPane.setTabPlacement ( JTabbedPane.EAST );
```

Comment: It is to me an important point.  It would be convenient to have them separated as needed.  For example in the north position I could have a JPanel containing first a set of buttons, then the tabs, and in the center position the tab content area.  I cannot do this with the JTabbedPane, as far as I know.

Comment: @jerome yep, you cannot do that with standard JTabbedPane. And also as i said in the answer - there is no way to separate JTabbedPane tabs from content. There is a lot of reasons for that, but i doubt they are interesting for you since all of them have roots in the UIs and L&Fs that Java provide for various systems.

Comment: Well there is a way to do it, but it seems to be way too complicated.  It would be to have a component with a BorderLayout.  That component would contain one component in which I can draw tabs, and another JPanel with a CardLayout for the tabs content area, and use MVC to display the correct content for the selected tab.  But it means that I have to implement most of the functionalities provided by the standard JTabbedPane. No other (simpler) solution ?

Comment: @jerome that way automatically excludes JTabbedPane usage. And well, its the only correct to do something "custom". Ofcourse you can create your own TabbedPaneUI that will allow you to put custom content within the tabbed pane parts, but that will be much harder than to do a totally new component that offers the same functionality. And i don't know any components that allows such a behavior. Maybe you can check the Jide components demo and find something useful in their custom tabbed panes - http://www.jidesoft.com/.